# What is wrong with my banshee installation and how can I fix it?

Tags: banshee, mono

When I try to launch banshee this what I get:

```
[Info  20:28:13.619] Running Banshee 2.2.0: [Ubuntu oneiric (development branch) (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2011-09-23 04:47:58 UTC]
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "rgba"
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
  at Hyena.Gui.Canvas.Rect.set_Height (Double value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Gui.Canvas.Rect.op_Explicit (Rectangle rect) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListView`1[Banshee.Collection.AlbumInfo].OnSizeAllocated (Rectangle allocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb (IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
   at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)
   at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_show(IntPtr )
   at Gtk.Widget.OnShown()
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface.OnShown()
   at Gtk.Widget.shown_cb(IntPtr widget)
   at Gtk.Widget.gtk_widget_show(IntPtr )
   at Gtk.Widget.Show()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow.InitialShowPresent()
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface.Initialize()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow.InitializeWindow()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow..ctor(System.String title, System.String configNameSpace, Int32 defaultWidth, Int32 defaultHeight)
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod , System.Object , System.Object[] , System.Exception ByRef )
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Object[] parameters)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.RegisterService(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.Run()
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.Run()
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Initialize(Boolean registerCommonServices)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor(Boolean initializeDefault, System.String defaultIconName)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor()
   at Nereid.Client..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod , System.Object , System.Object[] , System.Exception ByRef )
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Object[] parameters)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup()
   at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup(Hyena.Gui.StartupInvocationHandler startup)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup()
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup(System.String[] args)
   at Nereid.Client.Main(System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.AppDomain , System.Reflection.Assembly , System.String[] )
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal(System.Reflection.Assembly a, System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.String assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.String assemblyFile)
   at Booter.Booter.BootClient(System.String clientName)
   at Booter.Booter.Main()
```

Yet, if I run `muinshee`, it works just fine. I reported a bug on launchpad, then was told to report a bug on bugzilla, but something tells me this is something wrong with my system. I tried removing `~/.config/banshee-1`, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get purge banshee; sudo apt-get install banshee`

Comment: Try to remove `~/.gconf/apps/banshee-1` and `~./cache/banshee-1` too.

Comment: @aquaherd: thanks for the reply. I will try this :)!

Comment: @aquaherd: PLEASE add this as the answer :D!!!! Thanks so much <3! Deleting the gconf directory worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove ~/.gconf/apps/banshee-1 and ~./cache/banshee-1 too;

However it would be worth reporting to the banshee team. The call stack looks like they want to save and restore the width and height of the user interface but fail to handle missing or invalid data - kindly ask them to write a catch clause within `Nereid.PlayerInterface.OnShown()`.